# hide div with flip effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to website development. My code is working perfectly. The thing I just want is that, when I click on the first `div` it disappears with a flip animation and the second `div` appears. Then when I click on the second div the same animation happens as the third div appears. I just want CSS or jQuery code to flip the div when it disappears.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 abc">
        <div style="background:grey">
            text here
        </div>
        <div style="background:blue;display:none">
            text here
        </div>
        <div style="background:green;display:none">
            text here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.col-md-6').click(function() {
    var $current = $(this).find('div:visible');
    var $next = $current.next()
    if ($next.length) {
        $current.hide();
        $next.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean by a "flip" animation without an example. If you have some specific effect in mind, it would help a lot if you could direct us toward an example :)

Comment: i want this type of flip aniimation  [Example here](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-02-slide-flip.html)..when i click on div it flip like this way and disaapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
$('.col-md-6').click(function() {
 var $current = $(this).find('div:visible');
 var $next = $current.next()
 if ($next.length) {
  $current.animate({
   borderSpacing: -180
  }, {
   step: function(now, fx) {
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
    $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $(this).hide();
   },
   duration: 'slow'
  }, 'swing');
                $next.animate({
  borderSpacing: -360
 }, {
  step: function(now, fx) {
   $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
   $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
   $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
  },
  duration: 'slow'
 }, 'swing').show();
  
 }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your Code...Can i slow the speed of flip animation... @Gagan

Comment: set value of "duration" to miliseconds which will slow it down as per your need.(Example : for set one second change duration : 1000)

Comment: change borderSpacing to -180 to achieve what you want

Comment: IS there anyway that..when i click on first div..it hides and the second div appear with animation...please help me..i am stuck in it...@gagan

Answer (score 0):

Its quite tough to get a idea about which flipping idea you need . This is a link of a work which is a library . And I hope it can help .

[FLIP LIB](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/)

Answer (score 0):

On the link you provided as an example, you can follow a couple links that bring you to the example page, that has all the [source code](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html) and a detailed tutorial how to achieve the exact effect you wanted. It pays to look around a bit first!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
 $('.col-md-6').click(function() {
   var $current = $(this).find('div:visible');
   var $next = $current.next()
   if ($next.length) {
       $current.hide(1000);
       $next.show(1100);
   }
   });
```